# Same JavaScript function for two different buttons(I/O button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two  which are created dynamically,

```
<div id="flipbutton1" class="flipButton">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:ActionFunction('tcp.php',0);">OFF</a></li>
      <li class="on"><a href="javascript:ActionFunction('tcp.php',1);">ON</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

also this

```
<div id="flipbutton2" class="flipButton">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:ActionFunction('tcp.php',0);">OFF</a></li>
      <li class="on"><a href="javascript:ActionFunction('tcp.php',1);">ON</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to use this same JavaScript function but on different  id.
Example is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flipbutton1 ul li").click(function(){
        $("#flipbutton1 ul li").removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on"); 
    });
});
```

Problem:
It should work in such a way that when I click flipbutton1 it should work the same way but when i click flipbutton2 it should chanhge #flipbutton1 to #flipbutton2.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Give them both  a common class and then use JQuery!!!!

Comment: @Ninja_Noob The OP is using jQuery...

Comment: i am using the same class for both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want only one of the `<li>`s on?

```
$(".flipButton ul li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().andSelf().toggleClass("on");
});
```

Comment: when one <li> is "on" flipbutton1 when other <li> should be "off" , same for flipbutton2

Answer (score 0):

Edited version: 
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flipbutton ul li").click(function(){
        $(".flipbutton ul li.on").removeClass("on").addClass("off"); 
        $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
    });
});`

This ought to work even if you add more flipbuttons, as long as they use the .flipbutton class.

Comment: flipbutton1 has two state "on" to "off" and also flipbutton2 has the same state

Comment: I've edited my post to something I believe will work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flipButton ul li").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("on")
    });
});
```